# Hahn-Banach Extension

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

> Consider the vector space $c$ of sequences $x=\{x_n\}$ that converges in
> $\mathbb{F}$. Show that there is a linear functional $L \in (\ell^\infty)′$ so that $L(x)=\lim_n{x_n}$ for each $x=\{x_n\} \in c$.

**My attempt:**

Let $L$ be the linear functional on c. Given that $p(x) = \limsup_n{x_n}$ and $p$ is sublinear, let $\ell$ be the linear functional on $\{0\}$ given by the zero functional. Then $p(0) = 0 = \limsup_n{0_n}$ and by Hahn-Banach $\ell$ can be extended to a linear functional $L$ on $(\ell^\infty)'$ such that $L(x) \leq p(x) = \limsup_n{x_n}$ for all $x \in \ell^\infty $.

Applying this to $-x$ we get $-L(x)=L(-x) \leq \limsup_n{(-x_n)} = -\liminf_n{x_n}$, and, therefore, $\liminf_n{x_n}\leq L(x)\leq \limsup_n{x_n}$.

Since $\limsup_n{x_n}\leq \sup_nx_n \leq \sup_n|x_n|$ and also $\liminf_n{x_n} \geq \inf_n{x_n} \geq -\sup_n|x_n|$, we have $|L(x)| \leq ||x||_\infty$ and $L$ is bounded with norm $\leq 1$ for each $x=\{x_n\} \in c$.

Is my conclusion correct?

Comment: You need a larger subspace to start with, else your extension could very well be the zero operator.

Comment: Oh thank you, what should I use?

Comment: Your attempt seems correct to me. Hahn-Banach is applied correctly and as convergence means equality of $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ the functional is reproducing the limit on $c$. Larger subspaces are usually used to convert further properties of the limit to $L$ (such as shift invariance, for example in the definition of Banach limits).

Comment: Thanks @almosteverywhere. Does it look good now?

Comment: @AnalysisTux see my comment on the answer.

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan , does it look ok for you now?

Comment: May be this could be helpful. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_limit

Comment: @almosteverywhere I think extension from the trivial space $\{0\}$ is sufficient. The extension satisfies $L(x) \le  \limsup x_n$. For example $x=(-1)_{n =1}^\infty$ shows that $L=0$ is impossible. Moreover the OP proved correctly for the extension form $\{0\}$ that $\liminf x_n \le L(x) \le \limsup x_n$. Hence $L(x)=\lim x_n$ for $x \in c$.

Comment: @Gerd I haven't double checked it but what you have written seems right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose your linear subspace to be $c$ with $L(x)= \lim_{n}x_n$ and then extend your $L$ by Hahn--Banach since it will be dominated by $p$. It will then have the desired properties.

Comment: is $p(x)=lim_n{x_n}$ or $L(x)=lim_n{x_n}$?

Comment: $L$ should be $\lim_n x_n$ on $c$ which is the subspace of your big space $\ell^\infty$. $p$ should be $\limsup_n x_n$ from which it is clear that $L$ is dominated by $p$ and so we can extend it to a linear function on $\ell^\infty$.

Comment: maybe now? check the attempt above

Comment: Yes, I don't think you need the last 2nd and 3rd paragraphs of your answer. You construct the extension in the first paragraph and it has the desired properties

Comment: Thank you very much!